# es6 import absolute path

Tags: angular, typescript

i have a tow angular project's and i wont to import a same "ts" file from those tow project's.

for this goal i wont to make a shared folder that they both project will import 
the file from this shared folder.

there is a way to do this?

i try to import the file by absolute address, like this:

```
import { Model } from 'D:/Projects/shared/service';
```

but it's not working

I followed those solutions but seam that it's not what i looking for.
[Refer a typescript file outside of project directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382106/refer-a-typescript-file-outside-of-project-directory)
[Files outside of project directory in angular2 seed project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44367620/files-outside-of-project-directory-in-angular2-seed-project)

there is another way to do this?

thanks a lot!

Comment: webpack helps u do that . read more here : https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/10/07/absolute-paths-javascript/

Comment: It only shows how to shorten internal addresses. not outside. I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is by design kind of a typescript limitation. You need to change your `rootDirs` in your `tsconfig.json` to be able to access files; typescript does not compile typescript files outside the `rootDir` of your project.

Alternatively, you should build your Shared library and add the output of that in your `tsconfig.json` under paths. If you're planning to release Shared separately that's how I would do it.

Comment: i try to play with the rootDir but without success. you can add a snippet of code that do it?

Comment: By default the TypeScript compiler assumes the root of the project is the same as the location of your tsconfig.json.

You can specify a new root by specifying the rootDir property of the compilerOptions property in the tsconfig.

Comment: you mean like this:  "rootDirs": [     
        "D:/Projects/shared/"
    ]
and than import like this:
import { Model } from 'service';
because it's not work